# How to Change Bootstrap Button Properties and Attributes using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, button, jquery-events

I am new to Bootstrap and jQuery, and am having trouble determining best practices for changing properties and attributes of `html` elements within `js` files.

For example, I have a button that is enabled by default and contains some text. On a click event, I want to disable the button but also change the button text and color.

I have some sample code below where you can see I've been working through some button changes and testing the results. Also, I've referenced that I should use `.prop` instead of `.attr` when employing jQuery v 1.6 or higher, and I am using jQuery v 3.2.1 for my project.

**HTML**

```
<!-- Submit Button -->
<div class="form-group">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#submitModal" id="submitButton">Submit</a>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#submitButton").click(function(){

  //Disable button
  // $("#submitButton").prop('disabled', true) //Did not work
  // $("#submitButton").attr('disabled', true) //Did not work
  $("#submitButton").addClass('disabled')

  //Use aria-disabled when button disabled for screen readers
  $("#submitButton").prop('aria-disabled', true) //How to confirm this worked?
  //$("#submitButton").attr("aria-disabled","true") //use `.attr` instead of `.prop`?

  //Change button color
  $("#submitButton").button('reset').addClass('btn-success'). //Do I need `.button('reset')? Works fine without this code snippet as shown below in next line of code

  //Change button text
  $("#submitButton").html('Submission received') //Again, should I use `.button('reset') before `.html('Submission received')?

  })
})
```

Comment: How about `removeClass`?

Comment: You wish to disable the button *right after* it is clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About `disabled`, that is a property, so use [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

About background-color and text color, that is to be changed using [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/).

About button text, that is [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

```js
$("#submitButton").click(function(){
  console.log("HEY");
  $(this).prop("disabled",true);
  $(this).css({"background-color":"red", "color":"white"});
  $(this).text("I'm disabled");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="submitButton">Submit</button>
```

This has nothing to do with Bootstrap...

The "chained" way:

```js
$("#submitButton").click(function(){
  console.log("HEY");
  $(this).prop("disabled",true)
    .css({"background-color":"red", "color":"white"})
    .text("I'm disabled");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="submitButton">Submit</button>
```